# How to do a JOIN over multiple Django models

Tags: python, mysql, django, join

The following models are given:

```
class Copy(CommonLibraryBaseModel):
    lecture = models.ForeignKey('Lecture', ...)
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=100, ...)

class Lecture(CommonLibraryBaseModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey('LectureCategory', ...)

class LectureCategory(CommonLibraryBaseModel):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', ...)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, ...)
```

I basically want to do the following query:

```
SELECT signature, display_name FROM lecturecategory as lc, lecture as l, copy as c WHERE lc.id = l.category_id AND c.lecture_id = l.id AND lc.parent_id=2;
```

How would I do that in Django? I could not figure out how to combine the different models.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT signature, display_name
FROM lecturecategory as lc, lecture as l, copy as c
WHERE lc.id = l.category_id AND c.lecture_id = l.id AND lc.parent_id=2;
```

will be :

```
Copy.objects.filter(lecture__category__parent_id=2).values_list('signature', 'lecture__category__display_name')
```

If you want a QuerSet of dictionnary in result, use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values) instead of values_list. Values_list return a tuple.
[Documentation about lookup relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You could get a queryset of `Copy` instances with the following filter

```
copies = Copy.objects.filter(lecture__category_parent_id=2)
```

See the docs on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for more info.

You can then loop through the queryset, and access the related lecture and lecture category using the foreign key.

```
for copy in copies:
    print(copy.signature, copy.lecture.category.display_name)
```

Finally, you can change the initial query to use `select_related`, so that Django uses an inner join to fetch the lecture and category rather than separate queries:

```
copies = Copy.objects.filter(lecture__category_parent_id=2).select_related('lecture', lecture__category')
```